# Is there a way to recover java files from a android phone app?

Tags: android

I made an app in android studio that is now sitting in a compiled version on a few emulators and on my phone. Unfortunately my computer crashed and some progress got lost, however the most recent version is on my phone. Is there a straightforward way to extract the java source code again?

Comment: is api is in your phone or source code?

Comment: yes, you can extract java files if you haven't enabled proguard in your code. If you have enabled proguard in that case extracted files are useless for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the debug app already installed in your device, you can recover the source code:

1.) Install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.snowcorp.apps.apkshare&hl=en_US in your device

2.) Choose your app, click on share, then save the APK file.

3.) Finally, go to http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk and upload the APK and click Upload & Decompile button.

You'll get a zip file of decompiled source code. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This one working for me.

Go to Android studio 2.3, Build -> Analyze APK -> Select the apk that you want to decompile.
You will see it's source code.

Link for reference:
https://medium.com/google-developers/making-the-most-of-the-apk-analyzer-c066cb871ea2